# How to set dynamic coordinates on React map gl viewport

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

Im using React Map Gl to display maps on my app and right now I would like to add dynamic coordinates to show a place according to what was chosen. I cant see a way of doing that, i can only put the exact coordinates in the viewport

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "93vw",
    height: "35vh",
    latitude: -25.96628484128926,
    longitude: 32.595740826311584,
    zoom: 10,
  });
```

I tried to set the viewport state

```
 setViewport({ ...viewport, latitude: lat, longitude: lon });
```

And im getting a "@math.gl/web-mercator: assertion failed" error

Is there a way of solving this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have these dynamic data in another state/variable? if so can you set it to the viewport state?

Comment: Yes, i tried   setViewport({ ...viewport, latitude: lat });  setViewport({ ...viewport, longitude: lon }); but have a too many renders error

Comment: could you add the errors to the post? thanks